# correct time SQL

Tags: sql

I have time format like this in one of the tables: HH:MM SS

Example of time column is (like this I have 1 Million records):

```
 Time
 -------
 10:18 55
 10:20 17
 07:12 23
 11:38 27
 14:16 51
 10:24 16
```

I want the format to be: HH:MM:SS

```
 Time
 -------
 10:18:55
 10:20:17
 07:12:23
 11:38:27
 14:16:51
 10:24:16
```

The query I have written to do this is as below:

```
DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @colname VARCHAR(max)
DECLARE colcursor CURSOR
FOR
 SELECT time_1 FROM table1 WHERE time_1 like '[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] [0-9]
 [0-9]'
OPEN colcursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM colcursor INTO @colname
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

 SET @Query = 'update table1 set time_1' + '=' + 'cast(cast(replace(' + 
   @colname + ','+ ' ' + ',' + ':'+ ') as time) as char(8))'

 EXECUTE (@Query);
  FETCH NEXT FROM colcursor INTO @colname;

CLOSE colcursor;
DEALLOCATE colcursor;
```

The problem is this is keep on executing without any change as desired output. I don't think, this should take more time. Could anyone please help how to get the required output(that is, in HH:MM:SS format) ?

Comment: your example and expected are the same...?

Comment: what data type is your time column?

Comment: That's non-standard SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

i dont know why are you using dynamic sql.
it seems much simpler than what you have wrote

try this

```
Update table1
set time_1 = replace(time_1, ' ', ':')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table1 
SET time_1  =REPLACE(time_1 ,' ',':')
WHERE time_1 like '[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
Drop  table #Temp
;With cte([Time])
AS
(
SELECT '10:18 55' UNion all
SELECT '10:20 17' UNion all
SELECT '07:12 23' UNion all
SELECT '11:38 27' UNion all
SELECT '14:16 51' UNion all
SELECT '10:24 16' 
) 
SELECT * INTO #Temp From cte

SELECT * FRom #Temp --check time data Before Updating the table

Update I
SET [Time] = STUFF(i.[Time],CHARINDEX(' ',i.[Time]),1,':')
From #Temp I
Inner join #Temp O
On i.[Time]=o.[Time]

SELECT * FRom #Temp ---check time data After Updating the table
```